# Fullcalendar js eventClick on dynamically added events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have the following js:

```
    !function ($) {

  $(function(){

    // fullcalendar
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var addDragEvent = function($this){
      // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
      // it doesn't need to have a start or end
      var eventObject = {
        title: $.trim($this.text()), // use the element's text as the event title
        className: $this.attr('class').replace('label','')
      };

      // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
      $this.data('eventObject', eventObject);

      // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
      $this.draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
      });
    };
    $('.calendar').each(function() {
      $(this).fullCalendar({
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'today,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
              // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
              $(this).remove();
            }

          }
        ,
        events: [
        ],
          eventClick: function(event) {
              alert('win');
          }
      });
    });

      getEvents();

  });
}(window.jQuery);

function getEvents()
{

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Calendar/findEvents',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            request: 'ajax'
        },
        success: function (data)
        {

            if(data.length > 0)
            {
                for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index)
                {
                    var d = new Date(data[index]['end']);
                    if(data[index]['is_online'] === 1)
                    {
                        var myevent = {title: 'Forløb: '+data[index]['academy_name'].toUpperCase()+' \n   Modul: '+data[index]['module_name']+ '\n Type: E-learning',start: new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate())};
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var myevent = {title: 'Forløb: '+data[index]['academy_name'].toUpperCase()+' \n   Modul: '+data[index]['module_name']+ '\n Type: Kursus'+ '\n Lokation: '+data[index]['location']+'\n Underviser: '+data[index]['mentor'],start: new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate())};

                    }
                    $('.calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myevent, true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see when the calendar is loaded i am starting to load events (through ajax) into the calendar.

Now what i want to do is simply add an eventListner on each of the elements.

In the documentation it sates the following:

```
    eventClick: function(event) {
    if (event.url) {
        window.open(event.url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which i attempted with just a simple alert (as you can see in the code:

```
    eventClick: function(event) {
     alert('win');
}
```

However when i click my items nothing happens.

Can anyone tell me what i am missing?

Comment: Have you checked if any error appears in the javascript console ?

Answer (score 0):

I know you are loading events through AJAX, but have you tried returning an array of objects (the events) to the events array in your instantiation of the calender? Right now you are passing an empty array, so the plugin is not assigning any elements as 'events', and thus isn't assigning any click handlers.

```
 events: [  getEvents()

 ],

 eventClick: function(event) {
    alert('win');
    }
});
```

And then inside your `getEvents()` function call, rather than render the events, you should just return the event objects.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way to load events with an ajax call + some manipulation on the data you receive is to use your function as an event source ([link to the doc](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/)) :

```
$(this).fullCalendar({ ...
    events: function(start, end, tz, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Calendar/findEvents',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                request: 'ajax'
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // build an array of event objects with the data
                var events = ...

                // use the "callback" argument to load them in the grid :
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    },
    ...
 });
```

note : the signature of the function depends on the version of fullcalendar you are using. Versions prior to version 2.0 do not have the `tz` argument (again, check the doc).

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar is processing your listeners with no events. Your ajax is loaded after the initialization of your calendar. You could keep your current code and add the listener on eventRender.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     eventRender: function(event, element, view){
        element.click(function(){
            alert('test');
        })
      }
    });
```

I would probably suggest loading the events as suggested in the other answers though, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     eventRender: function(event, element, view){
        element.click(function(){
            alert('test');
        });
        $("#calendar .fc-helper-container").find("a").remove();
     }
});
```